# Dirichlet series of powers of the prime omega function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, dirichlet-series

Let $\omega(n)$ denote the number of distinct prime factors of a positive integer $n$.

I was wondering what is known about the dirichlet series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\omega(n)^k}{n^s},$$

in which $s>1$ and $k$ is a non-negative integer. Furthermore, I am curious whether this dirichlet series is meaningful in some context. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, it converges absolutely for $\Re(s) > 1$ and defines a holomorphic function. But more than that, it's probably not particularly interesting. One usually studies Dirichlet series associated to *multiplicative* functions.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Well, replacing $\omega^k$ by $\exp(\omega)$ will make it multiiplicative. What can you say then?